# running npm install gives me these errors

Tags: node.js, angular, npm-install, node-sass

`I have tried a lot of things in order to fix this but can t find a solution, installed node sass that just added more problems, it used to run without a problem now I keep getting errors`

```
npm ERR! code 1
    npm ERR! path D:\sb-app\node_modules\node-sass
    npm ERR! command failed
    npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node scripts/build.js
    npm ERR! Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe D:\sb-app\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
    npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
    npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
    npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
    npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'D:\\sb-app\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
    npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
    npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
    npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
    npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
    npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
    npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
    npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
    npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
    npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.2.0 | win32 | x64
    npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
    npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
    npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
    npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
    npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (D:\sb-app\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (D:\sb-app\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (D:\sb-app\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\sb-app\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\sb-app\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\sb-app\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:194:21)
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed  python2 Error: not found: python2
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (D:\sb-app\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (D:\sb-app\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (D:\sb-app\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\sb-app\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\sb-app\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\sb-app\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:194:21) {
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed }
    npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` succeeded python C:\Python39\python.EXE
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: C:\Python39\python.EXE -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack                       ^
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:326:12)
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:365:28)
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1067:16)
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:301:5)
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19042
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\\sb-app\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd D:\sb-app\node_modules\node-sass
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.2.0
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
    npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Ionutz\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-05-21T08_51_40_333Z-debug.log
```

I have no idea what to do I tried to install node-sass too but didn t work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

npm errors can sometimes be very (arguably, overly) verbose. The interesting part of the error is this:

```
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
```

The package you are trying to install has a native part that's compiled locally using gyp, and as part of its tooling, npm needs python2 to execute the build.
You need to make sure you have python2 installed, and that the executable is part of the path.

Alternatively, if you have python installed but it's named differently, you can tell npm what executable to use by calling

```
npm config set python /path/to/your/python
```

Comment: I did this, got a new problem now when trying to start the angular project does this
C:\Users\Ionutz\AppData\Roaming\npm/node_modules/node/bin/node: line 1: This: command not found, I used git bash, when i lauched it with powershell it worked

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue. Try to deleting package-lock.json and then rerun 'npm install'.

Comment: Pretty sure your error was something unrelated to the one OP was getting.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue yesterday. I fixed it by making sure I had python downloaded in the default directory and installing Windows Build Tools, since node-sass requires node-gyp which in return requires Windows Build Tools.

You can download it using an admin shell, but it is equally as easy to go to this [page](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2019), then find and download 'Build Tools for Visual Studio'. A good video explaining the process can also be found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P4_R34Lb-PE&ab_channel=Crawl). As mentioned before, you can install with powershell providing it is run as admin, this process can be found on it's npm page [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/windows-build-tools).

It might be worth deleting your node modules folder and re-running npm install once this is done.